# How to download file send from flask send_file to angular 5

Tags: angular, flask

I have endpoint which looks like following

```
@my_blue_print.route('/get_pdf', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def get_pdf(): 
      send_file('test.pdf', attached_file_name='test.pdf', mimetype='application/pdf)
```

This works in sense that I am able to download file using postman. However, I am not able to download file download using Angular 5

Code for Angular5 is as follows:

```
httpOptions = {
   header: new HttpHeaders({'responseType': 'application/pdf', 'Content-Type': 'arraybuffer', 'Accept': 'application/pdf'})
this.http.get(this.url, httpOptions).pipe (map (res:any) => {
 retun new Blob([(<any>res)], {'type': 'arraybuffer'}})).subscribe(result => {saveAS(result, 'test.pdf')})
```

However this doen't work, it throws following error:

unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Comment: You have created some `HttpHeaders`, but you don't send them during the get. You are just concatenating them to the URL. It might with better like this: `this.http.get(this.url, httpOptions)`.

Comment: That was my bad, i change code, it is still same issue